# Laravel's Storage::put not saving file based on original uploaded file extension. (e.g. Uploaded .ai saved as .pdf)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to upload an Adobe Illustrator (.ai) file and using Storage::put() saves the file as a pdf.

**Problem**

This is the uploaded file.

[image]

Upon multiple attempts, I've confirmed that they're all saved as .pdf.

[image]

How do you solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Upon peeking into the AI file, I've found that this is the reason why it's picked up that way.

[image]

I have not understood why the saved file has its extension changed, but using Storage::putFileAs() instead of Storage::put() solves my current problem. It is most likely a bug in Laravel framework.